# SSH password login: iptables Log/Drops listsDST=18.9.2.13/18.7.33.13

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, iptables

*Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.*

My machine is Ubuntu Server 15.04 with OpenSSH_7.1p2 Ubuntu-2, OpenSSL 1.0.2f 28 Jan 2016 installed. If I login via SSH and password in my Iptables log file there is connection dropped by IP DST=18.9.2.13/18.7.33.13 [Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT-2)].

```
Mar 28 22:18:54 server kernel: [2422326.749123] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.7.33.13 LEN=196 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22263 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41393 DPT=88 LEN=176 
Mar 28 22:18:54 server kernel: [2422326.780661] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.9.2.13 LEN=196 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=9434 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=57141 DPT=88 LEN=176 
Mar 28 22:18:54 server kernel: [2422326.813459] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.7.8.13 LEN=196 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=63006 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35380 DPT=88 LEN=176 
Mar 28 22:18:54 server kernel: [2422326.813502] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.7.33.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=747 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41634 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:18:55 server kernel: [2422327.811773] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.7.33.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=748 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41634 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:18:55 server kernel: [2422327.814570] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.9.2.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57805 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46622 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:18:56 server kernel: [2422328.811724] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.9.2.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57806 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46622 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:18:57 server kernel: [2422329.811689] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.7.8.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=58556 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35580 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:18:58 server kernel: [2422330.815651] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.9.2.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57807 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46622 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:18:59 server kernel: [2422331.815588] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.7.8.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=58557 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35580 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:19:01 server kernel: [2422333.823519] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.7.33.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=750 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41634 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:19:02 server kernel: [2422334.823476] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.9.2.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57808 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46622 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:19:03 server kernel: [2422335.823413] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.7.8.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=58558 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35580 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:19:09 server kernel: [2422341.839163] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.7.33.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=751 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41634 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 28 22:19:10 server kernel: [2422342.847109] [IPT-LogDrop]: IN= OUT=enp4s0f0 SRC=192.168.178.3 DST=18.9.2.13 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57809 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46622 DPT=88 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Sorry, I've thought my question is clear.

Comment: Sorry, I've thought my question is clear: WHY? when logging in via SSH and password my machine wants to connect to MIT with then IP numbers 18.9.2.13 / 18.7.8.13 / 18.7.33.13.

Comment: Post the log from your `ssh` connection (`ssh -vvv thehost`). It will tell you. But I might guess that it is Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication configured or so.

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3u24d24txghqzu/ssh-vvv.txt?dl=0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log, you can see that the `DPT=88` (destination port is `88`, which is port for [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). Although from your log it is not explicitly visible, that some connection would be made to KDC (or whatever).

In your log, there is

```
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
```

Which tells you that you offer such authentication methods (`gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic`). You probably have Kerberos configured somehow.

If you just want to avoid this, you can disable these methods by putting into your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
 GSSAPIAuthentication no
 GSSAPIKeyExchange    no
```